# How to measure distance between two or more iPhone devices using ultrasounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, audio

I want to measure the distance between two or more moving **iPhone** by using ultrasound or whatever sound measure.

How can this will be possible?

Please help me

Regards

Comment: How to implement a way to measure distances in real time on the iPhone by using ultrasound? Is possible?

Comment: I dont think iphone has ultrasound.

Comment: I really want to vote this up...

Comment: Why is this question down voted? It is legit

Comment: not possible unless the iphones are moving in space with no other objects around the. ultrasonic waves are pressured air flows and will be reflected by any body or change in air properties.  you'll will not detect a moving iphone from a rock or Android phone. use Bluetooth or WiFi to ping other devices.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone does not provide any ultrasound capabilities has part of its specs. You would need the iPhone speaker to produce certain type of waves and also have a transducer to pick up the sound waves when they bounce back.

> Ultrasound pictures are made from sound waves which are too high
>   pitched to be heard by the human ear. The sound waves travel through
>   your skin and are focused on a certain part of your body by a scanning
>   device called a “transducer.” It picks up the sound waves as they
>   bounce back from organs inside the body.

You can get more information by going to the [iPhone specs](https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/specs/) and more information [here](http://sogc.org/publications/ultrasound-in-pregnancy/) about ultra sound.

### Maybe in the future we'll be able to do this with our iPhones ?

[image]

Comment: Other choice will be using waves sound for detect the distance between two iPhones. This is possible? You know other options?

Comment: you could send out a 20kHz modulated pulse but the scattering return would be full of noise and the crap microphone is band limited to probably 12khz?